# How to close the SlideMenu when onClick a button inside the 'menu'

Tags: android, mfslidemenu

I'm quite a newbie in Android, but manage to create a simple SlideMenu by referring to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OT76zDIeBe8
I've also created a few buttons in the 'menu' used to intent to other pages. The thing now is, I want it to be like when I clicked onto the button itself, the menu would automatically close and it'll show the page that I intent to. So is there any suggestions/codes that I can refer to?

Comment: Google recently added an inbuilt/native library available to android support library called Navigation Drawer. Below is the link http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html you can use.

Answer (score 1):

from the docs:
`getSlidingMenu().toggle();`